# Flatten XML into simple list with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document full of ICD10 codes formatted like this:

```
<ICD10CM.index>
    <version>2019</version>
    <title>ICD-10-CM INDEX TO DISEASES and INJURIES</title>
    <letter>
        <title>A</title>
        <mainTerm>
            <title>Abnormal, abnormality, abnormalities</title>
            <seeAlso>Anomaly</seeAlso>
            <term level="1">
                <title>chromosome, chromosomal</title>
                <code>Q99.9</code>
                <term level="2">
                    <title>with more than three X chromosomes,  female</title>
                    <code>Q97.1</code>
                </term>
                <term level="2">
                    <title>analysis result</title>
                    <code>R89.8</code>
                    <term level="3">
                        <title>bronchial washings</title>
                        <code>R84.8</code>
                    </term>
                    <term level="3">
                        <title>cerebrospinal fluid</title>
                        <code>R83.8</code>
                    </term>
                </term>
            </term>
        </mainTerm>
    </letter>
</ICD10CM.index>
```

I would like to end up with a collapsed list of items, but each item in the final list needs to reference its parent(s), potentially recursively. I would like the output to look something like this:

```
<codes>
    <code>
        <id>Q99.9</id>
        <description>Chromosome, chromosomal</description>
    </code>
    <code>
        <id>Q97.1</id>
        <description>Chromosome, chromosomal – with more than three X chromosomes, female</description>
    </code>
    <code>
        <id>R89.8</id>
        <description>Chromosome, chromosomal – analysis result</description>
    </code>
    <code>
        <id>R84.8</id>
        <description>Chromosome, chromosomal – analysis result – bronchial washings</description>
    </code>
    <code>
        <id>R83.8</id>
        <description>Chromosome, chromosomal – analysis result – cerebrospinal fluid</description>
    </code>
</codes>
```

I'm fairly new to XSLT and have only built a handful of transforms, so huge bonus points for helping me understand the answer instead of just providing a code snippet that does the job.

This `level="3"` example is the most deeply-nested sample I found in a quick search of the data but I'd prefer an example that works for any depth.

Edit: Since folks have asked, I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Please state if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (or 3.0).

Comment: Also, why do **some** descriptions in your expected output include the id?

Comment: Not sure your overall goal here, but my CRAN 'icd' package for R already does this for the whole ICD-10-CM XML definitions, and has pre-compiled data frames which might be usable directly, as well as a range of tools for using these codes for good.

Comment: Apologies for the typos including IDs in my output incorrectly and for not specifying a version, edits have been made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it can be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ICD10CM.index">
    <codes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="letter/mainTerm/term[@level='1']"/>
    </codes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term">
    <code>
        <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="code" />
        </id>
        <description>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::term">
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </description>
    </code>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="term"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code should be self-explanatory - if not, ask.

---

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you could shorten this to:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ICD10CM.index">
    <codes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="letter/mainTerm/term[@level='1']"/>
    </codes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term">
    <code>
        <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="code" />
        </id>
        <description>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::term/title" separator=" - "/>
        </description>
    </code>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="term"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this could be made a bit more efficient by passing down the accumulated description as a parameter, instead of traversing up the entire ancestor axis for each `term`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ICD10CM.index">
    <codes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="letter/mainTerm/term[@level='1']"/>
    </codes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term">
    <xsl:param name="accumulated-description"/>
    <xsl:variable name="description" select="concat($accumulated-description, title)" />
    <code>
        <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="code" />
        </id>
        <description>
            <xsl:value-of select="$description" />
        </description>
    </code>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="term">
        <xsl:with-param name="accumulated-description" select="concat($description, ' - ')"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT 2.0 example works perfectly - one final question though, what if I wanted to include the `<title>` of the `<mainTerm>` in the output as well?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to include it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution in **XSLT 1.0** can be:

**Note:** I have tried to explain at each level via comments what the template or loop does. Let me know if I am missing something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="dash"> - </xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <codes>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </codes>
</xsl:template>

<!-- It matches all the <code> elements from the document -->
<xsl:template match="code">
    <code>
        <!-- Creates <id> for each <code> and puts the value of 'code int it'-->
        <id><xsl:value-of select="." /></id>

        <!-- Creates <description> tag and puts required values described below -->
        <description>
            <!-- Iterates through all <title> elements whose parent node is 'term' and who itself is preceding-sibling of 'term' 
            and gets the value of all such 'title''-->
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::term/preceding-sibling::title[name(parent::node()) = 'term']">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                <!-- It will join strings by '-' until the last element found -->
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dash" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <!-- Appends the value of 'title' who is preceding-sibling of current matching 'code' -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- If it is first <code> in the tree than it won't concat '-' -->
                <xsl:when test="not(ancestor::term/preceding-sibling::title[name(parent::node()) = 'term'])">
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::title" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($dash, preceding-sibling::title)" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </description>
    </code>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/93wkLJ4/1